# Flume HttpSource Permission Denied

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I have a flume with a httpsource.  When I start my agent I get permission denied error shown below.

ERROR org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource: Error while starting HTTPSo$
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

I am unsure what it is that has the permission denied to and how to fix it.

The flume I am using was taken from another post and is shown below.

[How to setup a HTTP Source for testing Flume setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657548/how-to-setup-a-http-source-for-testing-flume-setup)

Thanks

```
###############################
tier1.sources = http-source
tier1.sinks = local-file-sink
tier1.channels = ch3

# Define / Configure Source (multiport seems to support newer "stuff")
###############################
tier1.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
tier1.sources.http-source.channels = ch3
tier1.sources.http-source.port = 81


# Local File Sink
###############################
tier1.sinks.local-file-sink.type = file_roll
tier1.sinks.local-file-sink.channel = ch3
tier1.sinks.local-file-sink.sink.directory = /var/log/flume
tier1.sinks.local-file-sink.rollInterval = 5

# Channels
###############################
tier1.channels.ch3.type = memory
tier1.channels.ch3.capacity = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's because I was using port 81.  I changed it to 8989 and it worked.

Change

```
tier1.sources.http-source.port = 81
```

To

```
tier1.sources.http-source.port = 8989
```