# retrieve google analytics data with Hadoop Flume

Tags: api, hdfs, google-analytics-api, flume

I would like to retrieve Google Analytics Data using the Google Analytics API. I want to do this with Hadoop Flume to store them on hdfs.

For example, I want to retrieve the result of this http call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A92525220&start-date=2016-08-25&end-date=2016-08-25&metrics=ga%3Asessions&access_token=XXX
```

I can find a flume configuration to collect HTTP queries on this post: 
[How to setup a HTTP Source for testing Flume setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659879/1875861)

However I cannot see an http URL and I am confused about how to use it.

Could you provide an example of how to retrieve Google Analytics API data or any API with Hadoop Flume?

Do I need intermediate coding (java, python...) to call the API? Isn't it the role of Flume to directly call the API?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Http-source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#http-source) and if it doesn't fit your needs, then go with 
[Custom source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#source)

Comment: In the HTTP source example I give in my post, there is no URL with parameters, so I don't understand how to use it. Is there a url parameter in HTTP source?

Comment: @rom, sorry, my bad. Http source will not work,  its a listener for get & post requests.
You have to go with custom Flume source. Flume doc has a good example to start with it